# How to calculate coins combination for an amount of change money?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

I'm trying to create a change program in Delphi/Pascal. I have the values $0.05, $0.10, $0.20, $0.50, $1.00 and $2.00, and an unknown amount x. I need to be able to give the amount of coins per denomination that makes up x amount. Unlimited amount of coins of any denomination, it doesn't matter about that bit.

I have tried this for 5 days, but for the life of me, I have nothing to show for it. I've tried dynamic arrays, I've tried `for` (array) `do`, but it's just not working for me. If you can put me on the right track, that would be great!

#### Update:

OK, I have worked on it, but now I'm getting some issues that I can't figure out, which was part of the issue in the first instance. I keep getting the issue that it doesn't like my "coins". I tried to set it as an array, and it doesn't like that, I tried it as a constant array and then it didn't like that, I even tried it as a set, and that didn't work. This should work, but I've missed something. Any ideas would be great!

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  i : integer;
  change : integer;
  coins : double;
  coinage : integer;
begin
  coins := (0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1.00, 2.00);
  change := 4.00;
  while change > 0 do
    coinage := trunc(change/coins);
    change := change-coinage*coins;
    i := change - 1;
    while change>=1 do
    begin
      coinage := 0;
      i := coinage-1;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: If you've tried different array types then certainly you must have some code you tried that you can show? Start thinking about how you would solve the problem generally before getting into implementation details such as data types. Describe how you think you'd solve the problem. If you've done that and are having trouble translating that to Pascal, then describe that in your posted problem. If you can't just describe an approach to a solution, you'll never solve it in Pascal or any other language.

Comment: What is your general strategy to solve the problem?

Comment: 1. Write down, how you would solve that in real life. 2. Think about, why you solve it this way. 3. Try to get the math point of it. But don't try step 3 before 1

Comment: @koren: I make sure that future employers don't see this question when you apply for a job as a cashier. The people in your queue tend to get impatient after 5 days.

Comment: heh... I would hope that any job that I applied for as a cashier would have those sorts of systems sorted... Otherwise, I'm not being paid enough... :)

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I assume this does not compile right? What's the first error message you see? I can see firstly that you defined `coins` as a `double` (which is a number) but attempted to assign an array to `coins`. You cannot assign an array to a number in most computer languages. What languages are you familiar with? And have you looked at an Pascal online tutorials? Those should reveal fairly readily that `for (array) do` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
type
  TCoin = (cn5, cn10, cn20, cn50, cn100, cn200);
  TCoinValues = array[TCoin] of Currency;
  TMoney = array[TCoin] of Integer;

const
  CoinValues: TCoinValues = (0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1.00, 2.00);
  ZeroMoney: TMoney = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

function GetChange(Amount: Currency; out Remainder: Currency): TMoney;
var
  C: TCoin;
  N: Integer;
begin
  Result := ZeroMoney;
  for C := High(TCoin) downto Low(TCoin) do
  begin
    N := Trunc(Amount / CoinValues[C]);
    Amount := Amount - N * CoinValues[C];
    Result[C] := N;
  end;
  Remainder := Amount;
end;
```

#### Usage:

Drop a Button and a Memo on the Form, and assign this event handler to the Button's OnClick event:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  TestAmount = 12.97;
var
  Change: TMoney;
  Remainder: Currency;
  C: TCoin;
begin
  Change := GetChange(TestAmount, Remainder);
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%m breaks down into:', [TestAmount]));
  for C := Low(TCoin) to High(TCoin) do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d x %m' , [Change[C], CoinValues[C]]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%m remains', [Remainder]));
end;
```

#### Result:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!!!! This is what i was looking for!!! I did have to change the way the constant was called. Made it a variable that could be called from elsewhere, but it works, it shows exactly what I needed! Thank you EVER so much for your awesome help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to the problem is a little bit incorrect. It sounds as if you're thinking about what data types you're going to use, without first thinking off a solution to the problem itself. What you need first, is an `algorithm`, that is a sequence of actions that produces the final result, in your case - the amounts of coins per denomination. There are around 16 types of common algorithms, and the one you're most likely going to need to solve this problem is `dynamic programming`, or if you're not required to get the `minimal` amount of coins, but just get any possible way of getting coins to add up to the amount x, then `greedy algorithm` should do the trick. When you have your algorithm at least in your head, then it will be so much easier to think off what data types you are going to need.

I wouldn't suggest you take up algorithmic problems, that you're unable to solve in a day or two, as this is a bit demotivating, at least it would be for me, unless that was assigned as homework or something.

Comment: It is very demotivating for me, and while I know the logic behind it, and I know how it should come out, I don't know enough about Pascal/Delphi to make it happen. Unfortunately, my work will only train me in Pascal/Delphi when I can prove I have some ability to understand and code something "simple". As my department has already been dissolved, they are giving me the awesome option to train as a programmer, but I need to prove myself first, otherwise, I get retrenched... No pressure at all... :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple enough problem from an algorithmic standpoint that you shouldn't have any trouble with it.  In fact, you always solve the problem, then you look for the tools.  Simply put, you start with the largest amounts and count off down your list until you run out.

However, one specific problem you will run into with Delphi/Pascal in solving this problem is that Delphi does not support fixed point decimal arithmetic (it does scientific notation through the FPU, which is good enough for scientific applications, not for accounting ones), which means you will need to come up with a solution around that (the "currency" type works sometimes, it will work here).  Given your problem, it's simple enough to do - you account things in pennies instead of fractional units and account for that within the code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  const
    coins: array[1..6] of integer = (5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200);
  var
    amount: integer;
    i: integer;
  begin
    amount := trunc(StrToFloat(Edit1.Text)*100);
    Memo1.Clear;
    i := 6;
    while i > 0 do
      begin
        while coins[i] <= amount do
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStrF(coins[i] / 100, ffFixed, 18, 2));
            amount := amount - coins[i];
          end;
        dec(i);
      end;
     Memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStrF(amount / 100, ffFixed, 18, 2) + ' left.');
  end;
```

In production code, I would add a check against the StrToFloat call for proper numeric input, but this is the basic idea of what you're looking at to solve the problem.

Comment: Dealing with integer why not use MOD and DIV ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the above algorithm... unfortunately it doesn't tell me what coins the change was broken into, it just says $0.00 left. The great thing, is that it actually compiles... which is more than I can say I managed to get! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Kozbot why is this checked as the answer if it doesn't do what you want?